# Is Logistic Regression Appropriate for this Question?

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models, matlab

I am attempting to predict the ranking of NBA teams next season based on the number of games they won this season. To do this, I thought I could use a logistic regression with historical data. As stated, my dependent variable is following season ranking, and my independent variable is current season ranking. For example, the Golden State Warriors had 36 wins in 2010-11, and they finished the 2011-12 season with the 24th best record in the league, and these 2 data points would serve respectively as my IV and DV.

My ultimate goal is to figure out what the odds are of a team that wins 35 games in the current season to have a top-10 record in the following season. Is logistic regression the best way to handle this problem? If so, is it ordinal or hierarchical? The MATLAB code I have been using is below:

`B = mnrfit(X,Y)
pihat = mnrval(B,35)`

where X is the current wins and Y is next season's ranking. I then summed the first 10 values of `pihat` to get my probability.

Is there a better way to be going about this?

Comment: Your ultimate goal doesn't seem to be a logistic regression problem, but more of a simple math calculation. If you take all of the teams that have won 35 games, and then count the percentage of those teams that then get into the top 10, you should have an estimate of the probability.

Comment: Logistic regression would be good for predicting the odds of a team getting into the top 10 based on their number of current wins. I don't use MATLAB, but your X and Y seem to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I do go with the logistic approach, is the model nominal, ordinal, or hierarchical?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You could use a binomial logistic regression, coding your response variable as Y = 1 if team has ranking < 10, 0 otherwise.

Comment: The MATLAB code requires a delineation of whether the model is nominal, ordinal, or hierarchical, so I was wondering if you or anyone had input on what type of model to use. My best guess is ordinal since the data is ordered from best to worst ranking, but I wasn't completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to divide it into "top 10" and "other" but, if you do, then logistic regression is correct.  But your dependent variable will not be "record" but, rather, "top 10" which will be coded "1" and "0" or something similar. Then there will be only one estimated probability and it will be binomial logistic regression.

If you wanted to predict actual rank (1st, 2nd, 3rd .... ) then it would be interesting.  You might try an ordinal logistic regression, but it's a lot of categories since there are so many teams in the NBA.  You might try an OLS regression for that problem.

Comment: It's difficult to see how any of these proposed models would be applicable in a competitive environment in which (therefore) the outcome for each team  is so interdependent on the outcomes of all the other teams.  Perhaps you could elaborate on the reasons why you think they would work?

Comment: Because results last year is related to results this year, even in the competitive environment.  In any case, i don't know if they would work, I'm just answering the question.

Comment: I'm concerned about the likelihood this is a poor answer--especially because you don't even know that it would work.  This site isn't for such speculation: you know that.  Our users deserve better.